# How to create a luminous led fabric

Tags: texturing, materials

I'm having trouble creating a bright LED fabric, can someone give me a way

[image]

I used this setting to create the led, but it wasn’t like the picture

[image]

Comment: Hello :). What have you tried so far and where *exactly* are you stuck? This isn't the best place to ask for full tutorials :).

Answer (score 2):

I know there's a better way to do this, but I only took a few minutes.  Hopefully it gets you started.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help